# Why isn't there an unsubscribe link in SO marketing emails?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, developer-story, email

Just got an email from Stack Overflow about updates to the CV section of the careers site without an unsubscribe link. According to CAN-SPAM emails require:

- A visible and operable unsubscribe mechanism is present in all emails.

[image: Marketing email]

Comment: The [privacy policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy) appears to back you up on this: *If we do send you information that you did not expressly request, we will provide you with a way to request that you don’t get any similar notices (opt-out).* It doesn't specifically say it'll be in the email but it does say there will be something. That said, I'm kind of surprised it **does** say that. Usually most sites specify that you'll get a few emails that you can't opt-out of.

Comment: From this [meta question on Careers emails](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239462/careers-site-spamming-not-sure-what-i-opted-out-of), they do put a link in to opt-out in the email itself, at least for those. Maybe this was a goof (or a bug, as you say)?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here's the gist:

- **There's a good reason why you can't unsubscribe** - Users who have CVs *need* to know that their professional profiles will be presented in a pretty significantly new way, both as a view available to employers and to users on Stack Overflow.  (Legally speaking, it's not a marketing email; it's a "transactional" email. In fairness, it *feels* like a marketing email, since it opens with a description of how nice the new thing will be.  But it's not encouraging *any* sales activity - you literally can't use the thing yet.)
- **There's *not* such a good reason that the email doesn't make clear *why* you can't unsubscribe.** We *all* go looking for that button pretty regularly. So any email that has a relationship or transactional message - and therefore doesn't have it - should instead put, "You're getting this because we *have* to alert you that you've purchased 42 live newts and they're shipping tomorrow."  And it should still point you back to other settings, so you can turn off other email settings for spite, etc.

The email was *not* sent to get more folks creating these. (Again, you can't even use it yet, unless you opt into a beta, which isn't mentioned in the email.) Plus it was only sent to users who already have CVs, since their appearance to employers will change when this goes out.  (Mostly in presentation style, but when you're talking about employment, it's not okay to surprise people.)

This change doesn't *actually* change your privacy in any way - Dev Stories will only be visible on the "main" SO profile if the CV was linked from there before. But the navigation changes make it *feel* more visible (it's a tab, vs a button that seems to send you elsewhere).

Given all that, it's pretty clear users needed to be notified just in case they had concerns about privacy or wanted to change their settings.  That's why the only bold header is about privacy, and the only call-to-action link is for privacy settings.

**But we still blew it by not making it clear *why* you can't opt-out of this kind of thing in the footer. That won't happen again.**

It looks like the issue here was that we have so few emails you can't opt out of (signup confirmation, etc.) that the "this is a one time email that you're getting because X" language may have been hard coded into them individually, and it just didn't happen here.

**Update:** We realized that about a third of the emails were still in queue and hadn't been sent yet.  We pulled those, so no one else will get one without the explanation. They'll go out next week once it's been added.

Comment: I agree that it isn't a marketing e-mail, because it concerns a policy change affecting existing accounts (the new policy being that in order to have a CV you must also have a "Developer Story" -- did no one read the feedback that "developer" is not the correct title for all users of SO Careers?).  However, the reason you actually gave -- that the new stuff can't actually be acquired yet -- has nothing to do with not being categorized as a marketing email, as plenty of "announcement of future stuff" emails are required to abide by CAN-SPAM.

Comment: I would like to opt out of all Careers related emails by deleting my CV, but it doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: @JJJ I'm sorry to hear that you want to delete you CV entirely. Still, drop us an email at careers@stackoverflow and we'll get that taken care of for you.