# Getting Developer Story email every day morning

Tags: bug, developer-story, notifications, email

I am getting an email about my Developer Story thing, every day morning around 10 am GMT. Is this a bug on the Cron Job or something that triggers it, which I am unaware of? AFAIK, I have enabled and moved to the Dev Story, and I am not sure why am I getting notified about this by email daily.

[image: email]

**Note:** I don't want to disable Email notifications for this, but this seems like a bug in the Cron Job to me. Can this be checked? I can provide more information if necessary.

Comment: Thanks @bluefeet. For some reason, I am not getting notifications from [meta] so I posted on [meta.se]!

Comment: can you check `To:` fields on the emails you've received? I only see 1 email message sent to your email address in our logs (same is true for your account id, I checked separately). My guess would be you created a sock puppet account for testing.

Comment: @m0sa Gotcha... :D Lemme check that. That was a bulls-eye. But still, why should I get four times? Weird. And yea, the first one was for my test account, and the second one is for me, while I have enabled my Dev Story looooong back. - This?

Comment: can we stop getting emails altogether when we disable emails? that's just spam (and illegal here)

Comment: @Ven Where are you located?

Comment: Anywhere in the EU should do, Praveen. It's illegal if unsollicited. It's illegal if there's no working opt-out

Comment: @sehe I am in the UK. Does it now count as EU? `:/`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Of course. Did I miss the news of the exit procedure being completed? Or even initiated?

Comment: @sehe LoL. Ha ha. Hopefully the exit procedure shouldn't happen.

Comment: @Ven we're in the middle of a big email refactoring project, that will allow you to do just that, across all our products.

Comment: @Ven it's not spam, it's an update to a service you use. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335146/923847

Comment: @matsemann it's a service I do not use, although they want me to use it. Definitely spam.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Same happened to me, and took me a while to realize why.

I have gmail account, with a gmail email address, let's call it `shadow-wizard-dummy@gmail.com`. (spam bots don't bother, it's not real email)

I'm using this for my main Stack Exchange account.

Few years ago,  I created a test account, sock puppet as some call it, using Stack Exchange OpenID and for email I put `shadow-wizard-dummy+sock@gmail.com`. That cause all emails to reach the same inbox, but as far as Stack Exchange is concerned **it's a whole different email and account**.

They send the email in bulks, to **all** accounts, so I got two same emails, with few weeks between them.

Seconds before posting an angry bug report, I checked the email details, just for fun and saw this:

> [image]

Conclusion: don't forget your socks. :)

Comment: Ha ha ah... Nice conclusion... Yea, this proves it.

Comment: The only place we can have a single sock is sock-puppets... `:D` LoL.

Comment: Socks need jobs, too!

Comment: @CodyGray LoooooL!

Comment: "*shadow-wizard-dummy at gmail [....] it's not real e-mail*" .... yeah it is, that's *my* e-mail address there. Thanks a lot :(

Comment: Oh hi @nef! Didn't know you are a sock... ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am going to erase all the evidence.