# Did I just get told off by email? If so, what did I do?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, email, welcoming

I just received an email from Stack Overflow with the subject "Stack Overflow - Guiding question askers - Part 1", which appears to be (quite patronisingly and passive-aggressively IMHO) telling me how to request clarification from an OP, before going on to advertise Teams.

It says that the email was sent because of my recent activity on Stack Overflow. To my knowledge, I haven't had any recent activity, other than a comment on Meta, being slightly critical of the developer survey.

Is this the result of a flag, or some bad behaviour on my part? If so, it would be good to know what I did.

For reference, the full text of the email is:

> ### Asking for clarification
>
> Guide question askers to provide you more information
>
> #### People don’t know what they don’t know
>
> When people aren’t as experienced in a technology as you are, they don’t know what they don’t know. This can make it challenging to get what you need in order to answer their question.
>
> *Based on **what you wrote**, it sounds like you need **a solution for this**. Is that correct?*
>
> ---
>
> #### Get clarification by using the format above.
>
> - (What you wrote) Summarize what you believe the question or issue to be.
> - (A solution for this) Summarize what you believe they need a solution for.
> - Ask if what you believe is correct. You are clarifying that you have interpreted what they need correctly.
>
> ---
>
> #### Have you heard about Stack Overflow for Teams?
>
> Start building your organization’s knowledge base for the long term and improve cross team collaboration and information sharing.
>
> <kbd>Learn more</kbd>
>
> ---
>
> *You’re receiving this email because your Stack Overflow activity triggered this tip or reminder.*

[image]

Additionally - perhaps it's just me, but I found the content and formatting of the email incredibly confusing and hard to understand what it was trying to tell me. I had to read it about 5 times to get that the statement starting "Based on what you wrote..." was supposed to be an example of a good comment. It reads like it's information aimed at me. Also, it's formatted to look like a link, so I spent some time hovering over it, expecting that it would take me to whatever I'd written that it was referring to. And then I had to come here to ask, because I'm still not really clear!

Comment: Interesting, I just got a mail with the same _based on recent activity_ with search tips, leading me to instantly permanently delete the mail and turn off tips and features mails (too bad because I like getting notified about new features). Also unsure why my recent activity would lead to me getting search tips, but at least it's not as passive-aggresive.

Comment: I don't agree it's either "passive-aggressive" or "patronising". I don't find it either. I do find it a bit unclear, though.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one who was a bit surprised by that email. If something really did trigger it it would certainly be helpful to know what.

Comment: @yivi _Based on your recent activity, here's some help doing X_ out of the blue implies you're bad at X and is somewhat passive-aggressive imo.

Comment: I received a similar, but different email about search. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397896/why-is-stack-overflow-telling-me-a-long-time-and-100k-reputation-user-how-to -- I'm not sure if they are duplicates or not. Something is up with these emails.

Comment: @ErikA There is nothing passive-aggressive in providing users with guidance, IMO. The question says the email was ill formatted and terribly confusing, I don't find that aggressive or patronising either. It's just this user's opinion.

Comment: @yivi - I mean, there are definitely _more_ patronising ways it could have been written, and maybe I'm being over-sensitive, but as someone who makes a real effort to be polite and professional in my activities here (and everywhere), it feels a bit rude to suddenly receive an email implying that I've done something unkind without any justification or citing of what it is that I supposedly did.

Comment: @yivi Agree to disagree. Sending specific users a mail, and stating it's _based on recent activity_ makes you feel singled out and approached personally, based on something you apparently need guidance with. Since this _based on recent activity_ is terribly vague, I don't know why I got singled out for this guidance, which is, _not nice_, imo.

Comment: Why is it patronising to imply you may have done something wrong? No matter how careful and how much effort one puts, one can err. This is feedback, like votes. It pays to heed feedback, instead of getting annoyed by it. Exactly like votes. This can likely be auto-triggered by flags, and if so it makes sense that no exact example is shown. E.g. comments may have been already deleted, and it's rarely productive to tell a user "your comments under this post were deleted because of x and ".

Comment: Got the same email and was equally confused. What exactly am I being told? Why am I being told it? And the advert for Teams on the bottom looks like it's part of the whole email too. Bizarre.

Comment: I suppose the reason I feel patronised by it is that it's (IMHO) blindingly obvious information. I'm therefore left feeling that whoever sent the email (and I understand that it might be automated) assumes I'm an idiot with no understanding of basic politeness.

Clearly there's a difference of opinion here, which is to be expected, but there's some irony in a message intending to make new people feel more welcome ends up (one again) alienating a more experienced member and leaving him feeling offended.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that comment shows an utter lack of imagination. I hope you do not find patronised or insulted, it's just how I feel about that comment. For me, it's obvious that you were sent a very likely automated message that could be useful for many other users for whom the guidance wouldn't be equally obvious. E.g. I find the guidance alright. So you see, blindingly obvious lies in the eye of the beholder, and sometimes it pays not to get offended too easily. I do find the message could be improved a lot, and that the Teams ad is quite confusing.

Comment: @yivi This is not because of flags, because I got this with tips for search, and there's no _user is using search statements poorly_ flag. I could imagine getting this when asking duplicates, but I didn't. And _you got this because you got multiple flags indicating your comments were not necessary_ is enormously more useful than _you got this based on your recent activity_. While I get you sometimes don't want to point to the exact errors, if you don't leave at least a clue as to what someone did wrong but imply they did something wrong nonetheless, that's rude imo.

Comment: @ErikA So what's patronizing and passive aggressive in sending you search pointers?

Comment: @yivi - he explicitly said above "at least it's not as passive-aggresive". I'm not sure why you're so upset about an opinion here. I find the message passisve-aggressive, at least one other person agrees. You don't. That's fine. But perhaps suggests that the wording could be reviewed if some people find it rude.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave wait, so the "based on what you wrote" line is *not* a link?

Comment: @TylerH - nope. I spent quite some time checking that. It's definitely not! It's not saying "Based on what you (i.e. I) wrote", if you read the next bit, after the line, it's telling you that that's how you _should_ write a comment asking for clarification.

Comment: I'm  not upset at all. I'm sorry if I communicated that. I simply disagree with the characterization of this message being "passive-aggressive" or "patronising". And I feel that that description makes it feel like you are the one upset, and distracts from an otherwise productive discussion.

Comment: I see, so someone flagged your comment then probably, and you got this automated email as a response. I agree, this email is about as clear as mud. The blatant, completely unrelated advertisement of Teams is rather annoying, too.

Comment: @yivi I think I can search perfectly fine, and I don't know what I did to deserve it. These "pointers" did exactly nothing to help me search better. The mail both wastes my time and implies I don't know how to search properly. That's rude imo. There are cultural differences in what is perceived rude, but in my culture, giving personalized, unsolicited, and very basic advice is just that, rude.

Comment: @TylerH - I guess, maybe. But as I said, my only activity for some time was a comment on a meta post about the developer survey, where I said that I didn't think the survey had any of the "fun" of previous ones. [The comment's still there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397792/2020-developer-survey-results-feedback?cb=1#comment772710_397792). If these emails _are_ triggered by flags, surely they aren't sent based on a single user's flag?

Comment: Frankly, on rereading it it doesn't even look like they are telling you did anything "wrong". It's just generic guidance. "Recent activity" may be a blanket "you were active on SO". If I were to guess, I'd say this is mostly generic guidance being sent as an excuse to push Teams ads. I dislike that, because it dilutes the usefulness of the message, and the bit about "activity" further confuses the matters. I find the message poor because of the above, not because of its perceived tone.

Comment: @yivi - absolutely, hence my question - "am I being told off?" I don't know. It kind of feels like it, although I recognise that it can be just as easily interpreted as an attempt at simple friendly advice. As Erik says though, the intrusion and waste of my time - if not the tone - are annoying. Given that I didn't opt in to such emails, I wonder if there's a GDPR issue with it.

Comment: This email is an example of the reason I mark emails from Stack Exchange as spam.

Comment: @SecurityHound I'm fairly sure this is the first email I've ever had from Stack Exchange. I guess I'll follow your lead though.

Comment: A side note. I do not find the content of the email offensive. However, given that this seems to be a new feature, I believe that it would be useful to (at least) make everyone aware of it in advance and explain how exactly it is meant to work.

Comment: @user9716869 - yes, with some more useful context about why I was being sent it, and that I wasn't necessarily being told off, it would have been far more innocuous as you (and yivi) say.

Comment: Quite often doing the things suggested gets you revenge downvotes and is discouraged by several meta posts that tell you to just "downvote and move on".

Comment: I ultimately removed the alt text  (explained why in my edit) but also wanted to leave a note that alt text needs punctuation; otherwise screen readers will read them as a run on sentence with whatever text on the page comes after it.

Comment: just got that e-mail today. Instead of creating a meta post, I just went "what the hell" and put it in the trash.

Comment: but yes, we're going to edit _all_ your answers starting now :)

Comment: Based on my opting out of emails I think I did the right thing.

Comment: I think every single person that gets this type of email should use the "contact us" link to ask for clarifications about what exactly they wrote to get this email.

Comment: @Scratte: Please don't. It'll just make unnecessary work people people who are already overworked. :-(

Comment: @JonEricson I'm aware of that. But if I had gotten this email, I would most definitely have perceived it as a warning about an activity I had performed. I would also have interpreted the lack of repercussions for what would happen if I did not as a part of the "welcoming"-thing. Leaving me to not only not know what I did wrong, but feeling threatened. Since I spend most of my time curating and have been made aware that some of my comments have been removed due to some mishaps and false-positives from the automated flagging of unkind comments, I'd have only the option of stopping my activities.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I appreciate your feedback, this is helpful.

This email is part of a four week educational email campaign we have started to offer tips and suggestions to question answerers to help guide question-askers. You received this because the system identified you as a user who has answered a question in the past 12 months. You did not receive this because of anything specific you wrote or said.

I hear what you are saying about the formatting of the email. I will take that back to our Design team and see if we can make things more clear.

Comment: Thanks for rereading what you wrote to us, some of us have fairly high Flair and *do* try hard to understand what is written and respond correctly; you've included a lot of people in your mass email who did not have this admonishment coming. --- After the *repair* I don't need to see the revision, write a Meta and feature it if you can't narrow your audience appropriately. --- We don't want to block important notifications.

Comment: This would be a better email if, at the very top of the email, it included verbiage substantially similar to the second paragraph in your answer above.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - captured and being brought back to the team. Appreciate it!

Comment: @Rob - captured and being brought back to the team. Appreciate it!

Comment: I understand the intent here, but perhaps you should exclude people who have posted a significant number of answers? Or do you feel we also need educating too? And please drop the adverts for Teams on the bottom too (or at the very least, don't make them feel like part of the education)

Comment: @DavidG I have a feeling it's like those mass emails you get at work where some number of individuals have done something wrong (like people failing a security audit) and the company sends out emails to everyone so that they don't accidentally divulge who failed the audit.  I *understand* the point of this email, but I sorely wish that Joy's second paragraph was included as pointed out by Robert.  When I first read the email, I was rather frustrated.

Comment: I'm amazed that "the team" didn't realize the implications of what they were sending, how it might be received and the size of the audience that would receive it. Makes me wonder if "the team" is a group without much experience actually using SO.

Comment: Sincerely thank you for engaging here and answering the question. That feels like a _massive_ step in the right direction in terms of the company's relationship with the community.

Comment: Please provide a mechanic to opt-in to these type of emails.  If I continue to receive low quality emails, I will flag as spam, which means I might miss information that is important.  I will never be interested in Teams, so any email that is an advert for Teams, will be flagged as spam.

Comment: As a former member on the SO Design Team, I have to say this isn't a design issue. No designers can dress up confusing content and copywriting.

Comment: I got this email and figured there was some mistake because I haven't answered questions on SO in ages. But it turns out [I answered in November](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986632/erlang-client-set-ssh-key/59075989#59075989). Guess I better think twice next time. In all seriousness, "Based on what you wrote, it sounds like you need a solution for this. Is that correct?" is very confusing. It sounds like this is the question Stack Overflow is asking me, but I really can't make heads or tails of it.

Comment: I agree that this email goes beyond design issues, @Jin

Comment: Shouldn't "using the format above" be "using the format *below*"?

Comment: @DavidG - thanks for the suggestion to exclude folks who have posted a significant number of answers. Slight topic change: was there anything that you felt could have helped you when you first started answering questions? Maybe something you learned over time or discovered on your own that you think would be helpful for others who are just starting to answer questions?

Comment: Note: sending unsolicited tone deaf emails to your core community is a great way to ensure your core community ignores any future attempts.  Marketing is a fine art, and a shotgun approach isn't the way to do it.

Comment: @fbueckert I'm sure I'm not the only one who designated the email as spam (which it absolutely is.. "unsolicited messages sent over the Internet, typically to a large number of users"). Gmail tends to take these things into account if enough people do so for future filtering purposes, etc., so if you haven't done so I'd encourage you to go back and mark it as spam.

Comment: This might not be the place for this, but I just wanted to say, the ads for teams are getting tiring, I've looked at what Teams offers once and decided that we have no use for it whatsoever, and other services like private wikis serve that need better; I may never in my career use Teams at this rate. If you're trying to increase exposure I understand that motivation, but it may not be worth showing ads to *developers* more than once unless something changed (i.e., features are added). Every time I see another Teams ad, I just say "yeah, know what that is, and I don't need that".

Comment: I recieved this email too and I am new to answering questions. I got very scared that I did something wrong. I've probably answered less than 2 questions in 2 years, and this week I started answering like 2-3, and then I got that email. I was sort of freaked out, but then realized this was generic.

Answer (score 131):

Wording and tone aside, I gotta address this:

> You received this because the system identified you as a user who has answered a question in the past 12 months.

Dear Stack Exchange Staff: [over half a million users fall into that bucket](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1245943); that's some incredibly sloppy targeting. There is a wealth of raw data on answerers who might benefit from some guidance here. If nothing else, looking back *a full year* is pointless; a big chunk of those folks won't have even visited the site recently, much less answered. Guidance like this only works when it's relevant - spamming folks who won't retain it just wastes their time and yours.

You know all of this already. Do better, please.

Comment: I can't remember his name, but a while ago there was some guy who worked for the company and was quite active in the community, and was pretty good at this sort of targeting. I wonder what happened to him.

Comment: Eh; if this was a bus factor thing I'd have a bit of sympathy, even for the bus driver. But... I know there are folks still there who can do this sort of work in their sleep; this smells like laziness.

Comment: but but but it might bring people 'back' to the site! and they'll become the best users ever!!!!1111oneone.

Comment: I know you're being funny, @djs - but that's not wrong. With a big enough net, you will tend to catch some specimens of every behavior imaginable and plenty you'd never have thought of. Due to how digital marketing operates, folks involved tend to get very accustom to both casting very big nets and retrieving very small success rates - but those expectations can trip you up big-time when it comes time to write for a (relatively) static audience. As always, it's important to define goals before strategies, and strategies before metrics.

Comment: My thoughts were that this isn't the only criteria for sending that email. Just that we are not told about the rest. Time will tell.

Answer (score 46):

It looks to me like Stack Overflow added this footer (in both this email [and this one about "how to search"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397896/why-is-stack-overflow-telling-me-a-long-time-and-100k-reputation-user-how-to) in order to **pretend these are transactional emails rather than marketing ones**. Transactional emails are things like "your order has shipped," or "there's been a comment on your post," and there's different standards for them in terms of spam laws and business practices.

[This answer from four years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335143/why-isnt-there-an-unsubscribe-link-in-so-marketing-emails?cb=1) discusses this, in the context of why there wasn't an unsubscribe link in an email about Developer Stories (emphasis is **mine** and differs from the original post)

> Users who have CVs need to know that their professional profiles will be presented in a pretty significantly new way, both as a view available to employers and to users on Stack Overflow. (Legally speaking, it's not a marketing email; it's a "transactional" email. In fairness, it feels like a marketing email, since it opens with a description of how nice the new thing will be. But it's not encouraging any sales activity - you literally can't use the thing yet.)
>
> There's not such a good reason that the email doesn't make clear why you can't unsubscribe. We all go looking for that button pretty regularly. **So any email that has a relationship or transactional message - and therefore doesn't have it - should instead put, "You're getting this because we have to alert you that you've purchased 42 live newts and they're shipping tomorrow."** And it should still point you back to other settings, so you can turn off other email settings for spite, etc.

As [Shog9 points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397901/712603), the set of "everyone who has answered at least one question in the last year" is half a million users, which isn't specifically targeted at all. But it still technically lets them say "your behavior on the site triggered this" rather than "we wanted to email half a million users who didn't ask for it."

---

In fairness to Stack Overflow, the message does have a link to "Unsubscribe from emails like this," so I'm not particularly bothered by it myself.

Comment: You know what happens when I get a email, and there's no unsubscribe link, and I didn't want/expect the email? I hit the lovely spam button, and poof, no longer my problem.... is that what they were hoping for?

Comment: @djsmiley2kStaysInside Depending on how involved I want to get, I sometimes point out that they are [literally breaking the law](https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/can-spam-act-compliance-guide-business).

Comment: Hahaha... Dave, I was reading your excerpt, and thinking, "I like that post's silly examples A LOT, but it'd be clearer with fewer words," and.... then I clicked through and realized *I* wrote it.  SIGH.

Comment: @Jaydles: I resent the implication that it's silly to have purchased 42 live newts at once! :P

Answer (score 28):

Based on the feedback we received, these email campaigns have been paused. Thank you all for bringing these concerns to our attention. We will use this feedback to improve targeting and messaging. Additionally, the Teams promo has been removed. Our goal is to provide additional education and guidance along the way for users and not send emails that aren’t relevant and useful.

Comment: Well, then case closed.

Comment: Thank you very much for the update.

For what it's worth, I don't think it was that far from the mark, if I'd received the same email but with some sort of header explaining that it wasn't targeted specifically at me, that it was a general campaign and that I shouldn't expect a deluge of similar emails, I'd have been perfectly happy. Even better with a link to a Meta post explaining the campaign.