# Why is Stack Overflow telling me, a long-time and 100k+ reputation user, how to search?

Tags: bug, search, email

I just received an email from Stack Overflow  with the subject line "Stack Overflow - Tips for searching". In the footer, it says "You're receiving this email because your Stack Overflow activity triggered this tip or reminder." I opt into all of the emails, so it's not unexpected that I receive emails from Stack Overflow regarding the use of the service. However, as a user with over 100k reputation on Stack Overflow, 10k+ on multiple other sites in the network, and a community moderator on one, why is the system telling me how to use basic functions like searching?

This may be related to this question: [Did I just get told off by email? If so, what did I do?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397895/did-i-just-get-told-off-by-email-if-so-what-did-i-do)

Comment: "I opt into all of the emails"... Well, *there's* your problem... `;-p`

Comment: To play devil's advocate, I *have* seen such high rep users asking blatant duplicates, so I'm happy to see them trying to help people figure out how to search on their site. Now, if the email doesn't start by saying "go to google instead" then it's probably not that helpful of an email...

Comment: I'm intrigued now that they have such a mail at all. But is it truly "Tips for searching" or just a reminder that the search bar and its pointless filters exist? And isn't it most likely you just got hit by the tip algorithm, because you use Google like any sane person?

Comment: It's just an excuse to advertise teams.

Comment: This comes off as slightly arrogant.

Comment: investigation in progress to find who accidentally pressed the "send" button ...

Comment: You searched something on SO. The SE search engine returned "0 results". The system assumes that is your fault. You need to be fixed ... ;)

Answer (score -7):

I appreciate your feedback, this is helpful.

This email is part of a four week educational email campaign we have started. You received this because the system identified you as a user who has asked a question in the past 12 months.

This specific email campaign is meant to offer tips and suggestions to question askers.

I hear what you are saying about your reputation which is something we didn't factor into the requirements. I will bring that back to the team to see how we can iterate for future emails.

Comment: You should also consider **spelling out, in the email, the specific action that triggered it**: ie “Because we noticed you asked a question in the last 12 months, we thought you might be interested in question-asking tips on SO...” (link to the specific question the user asked is optional). And I’d strongly recommend going beyond “considering reputation”: **target users who have had *poorly-received* questions** (definitely score < 0, maybe closed questions, maybe maybe score = 0 & no answers [not no-upvoted answers, literally no answers]).

Comment: @DanBron - captured and bringing back to the team. Appreciate it!

Comment: I realize this conflicts with the secondary/ulterior motive of finding opportunities to promote Teams to as wide an audience as possible, and targeting struggling users probably minimizes buyers, but ... this is the choice in front of you.

Comment: Based on this, I closed this question as a duplicate of the linked one since it's the same campaign. But yes - being more specific about why the email was sent (what action or inaction triggered it) and taking reputation of the user into consideration would be extremely helpful.

Comment: @ThomasOwens:  These are two different emails which have two different audiences/applications.  I'm not seeing this as a dupe.

Comment: @Makoto It appears that there is one educational email campaign that isn't properly targeting users based on criteria like reputation or site involvement.

Comment: @ThomasOwens:  I don't think that reputation was even considered for these email campaigns, so it's a reach to call it "improper".

Comment: Please provide an option, within the user profile, to prevent receiving these educational and promotional emails.

Comment: Please take me off of your mailing list for this kind of "how do I use the site?" nonsense, effective immediately.