# Received email: "People have given you solutions..." but none of my questions have been answered

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, email

Related: [Did I just get told off by email? If so, what did I do?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397895/did-i-just-get-told-off-by-email-if-so-what-did-i-do)

I just received an email from Stack Overflow. The full text of the email is:

> ### You’ve asked, now it’s time to accept an answer
>
> People have given you solutions, now it’s up to you to accept the answer that worked.
>
> #### Accepting an answer benefits you and the person who answered
>
> When a solution or answer works, make sure to accept the answer. Accepting an answer tells other people who may face the same problem that the solution works.
>
> To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer. You’ll earn 2 reputation points and the person who provided the answer will earn 15 reputation points.
>
> #### Take a break and read more about the worst coder in the world out of 7 billion other humans
>
> Button: [I need a break]
>
> ---
>
> You're receiving this email because your Stack Overflow activity triggered this tip or reminder.

As far as I'm aware, none of my questions have been answered (this will probably be my first). This is quite frankly a deceptive and frustrating email to receive.

Could the email be tuned to only be sent to people who it applies to.

Comment: How do you intend to tune it?

Comment: @MartinJames Maybe only send it to people with answered questions, probably: *"because the system identified you as a user who has had a question answered in the past 12 months"*

Comment: @MartinJames Ideally send it to new users who have had had their questions answered, and haven't accepted an answer yet.

Comment: We printed and mailed the solutions to you. You should receive them in [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/244695)

Comment: *This is quite frankly a deceptive and frustrating email to receive.* well, you're not the first. Also [seasoned users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397896/578411) got these kind of e-mails. I don't speak for the company at all but on behalf of myself I apologize that email got send to you.

Comment: Is it possible that one of OP's questions got an answer that was later deleted?

Comment: @BSMP that'd make some sense - but not the case here...

Comment: If would appear that all the frustrations that is evident from the other linked Questions haven't been heard by the people that needs to hear it. Or it's been ignored. This is of course not in the interest of Stack Overflow, since once someone makes changes to their profile or sets up spam filters, there a real risk that they will never undo those.

Comment: @Scratte It isn't perfect but my understanding is that all of the email drip campaigns we started as part of this project other than the "New user" one, were paused due to feedback. This seems to be from that new user group. I'm looking into it to see if we can pause all of them until we have a chance to review them more comprehensively. I really appreciate the feedback in this question, as it brings up very important points.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349437/stack-overflow-reminded-me-to-accept-an-answer-i-have-never-posted-a-question) (vitrtual dupe) on meta.se.

Comment: @Catija I've received a second email implying I've had my questions answered. Who should I contact to lodge a complaint.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does the "I need a break" button do?

Comment: It sounds like the filtering mechanism that was used to trigger these emails is faulty. Don't worry about it, this happens. In this post, "frustrating" sounds like an overstatement, and "deceptive" sounds plainly wrong. I know there is some resentment against the company at the moment, but I am not sure this is the right topic to post it on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recent series of email campaigns that launched the first week of June [have been paused](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398650/5516513). This particular series (for new users) was set to run it’s course (4 emails) for the first group who received the campaign at launch so that we could have a baseline of engagement to work from, but has been paused for new users after that initial batch. If you’ve received all 4, you shouldn’t get any more. You can also unsubscribe from ‘[Tips and Reminders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current)’ to be sure you don’t receive any more.

Your feedback about receiving this email when your questions have not yet been answered is very helpful, thank you. We’ll use this in the next iteration as we work on improving messaging and targeting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Much appreciated. Just to note that I received a second email today (before this answer), which also implies that I've had my questions answered.

Comment: Hopefully, this initiative has not been abandoned. I experience that many users (especially new users) do not accept any answer to their question. Also, I think deleting a question with an answer should always be subject to moderator review in order to counter misuse of the site to get help and then remove "the evidence" as soon as an answer is given (I have personally been on a break from contributing to the site after experiencing this).

Comment: @nielsen There is no serious issue in someone not accepting answers. And askers cannot delete a question already if it contains positively received answers underneath.

Comment: @E_net4thecurator It depends on the situation. If one or more answers fully covers the question, one of them should be accepted. Otherwise, the accept option could be entirely removed (which may be a valid simplification since the poster can upvote as anyone else). About deleting questions: I propose to extend the restrictions. In the situation I am talking about, the poster will remove the question before anyone had a chance to upvote the answer. If the problem is small, the effort to review is small. If the problem is big, it is worth the effort.

Comment: Better make that into independent posts rather than as comments in a tangentially related post, @nielsen.